# Using ajax for Kendo chart control

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I try to build a simple mobile app for my company that shows basic data. This data is retrieved by a webservice. When debugging my app in the Telerik Appbuilder and the simulator everything works as expected. but when I load the app on any device the aja request doesn't get any results or even causes an error. I have no Idea, what the cause for that error is, since I can't debug on the device. Here is the JavaScript I use:

```
var turnover = [];

var wturnover = [];

function drawToChart(e){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://b2b-test.actebis.com/invoke/Services.AlsoLive/getData?mode=tover&vkorg=1010",
      success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          var year = value.Category.substring(0,4);
          var month = value.Category.substring(4,6);
          var day = value.Category.substring(6);

          if(month.substring(0,1) === "0")
          {
            month = month.substring(1);
          }

          if(day.substring(0,1) === "0")
          {
            day = day.substring(1);
          }

          turnover.push({ Date: new Date(year, month, day), Value: value.Value });
        });

        $.ajax({
          url: "http://b2b-test.actebis.com/invoke/Services.AlsoLive/getData?mode=wtover&vkorg=1010",
          success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
              var year = value.Category.substring(0,4);
              var month = value.Category.substring(4,6);
              var day = value.Category.substring(6);

              if(month.substring(0,1) == "0")
              {
                month = month.substring(1);
              }

              if(day.substring(0,1) == "0")
              {
                day = day.substring(1);
              }

              wturnover.push({ Date: new Date(year, month, day), Value: value.Value });
            });
           $(e.sender.content[0].firstElementChild).css("margin-top", "0");
           $(e.sender.content[0].firstElementChild).kendoChart({
                theme: "metroblack",
                title: {
                    text: "Turnover"
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Turnover",
                    type: "line",
                    data: turnover,
                    field: "Value",
                    categoryField: "Date",
                    tooltip: {
                        visible: true,
                        format: "{0}k"
                    }
                },{
                    name: "Web turnover",
                    type: "line",
                    data: wturnover,
                    field: "Value",
                    categoryField: "Date",
                    tooltip: {
                        visible: true,
                        format: "{0}K"
                    }
                }],
                categoryAxis: {
                    type: "date",
                    baseUnit: "days",
                    labels: {
                        dateFormats: {
                            days: "dd"
                        },
                        rotation: 45,
                        step: 5
                    }
                },
                valueAxis: {
                    labels:{
                        format: "{0}K"
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom"
                }
            });
          },
        });
      }
    });
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you have no error, but I don't see any error handler for your ajax call. Have you tried launching an alert in the error handler ?

Comment: Yes, I've added an error handler to the ajax call and it never got fired.

Comment: I just retried to usw an error handler. It seems that I was to unpatient with My first try. The error handler was fired after some minutes. But the error message only said 'error'. What could be the Problem?

Comment: try to alert `jqXHR.responseText` or `errorThrown`.
`error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}`

Comment: I alerted the responseText but just get an empty string